OpenAI API key not found
This is the server response to my RAG Application
This is the code in which I am using using the OpenAI API key to access the services
I am encountering an error which is defined as "OpenAI API key not found" even if I am providing the right API key provided by the openAI platform.
I'm currently working on a Retrieval Augmented Generation (RAG) application using the Langchain framework. When creating the instance, I provide the API key generated from the OpenAI platform. However, I'm encountering an error that prevents me from accessing the services of Large Language Models (LLMs). My goal is to develop an application that allows me to modify the responses of the LLMs using RAG.

Please post the code you used in your question as well as the full error messages. While the images do provide some information, we need the code to reproduce the error. If the code is too large or complex, please provide a MRE.
